# How would you vectorize this nested loop in matlab/octave?

Tags: matlab, octave, vectorization

I am stuck at vectorizing this tricky loop in MATLAB/Octave:

```
[nr, nc] = size(R);
P = rand(nr, K);
Q = rand(K, nc);

for i = 1:nr
   for j = 1:nc
      if R(i,j) > 0
          eij = R(i,j) - P(i,:)*Q(:,j);
          for k = 1:K
          P(i,k) = P(i,k) + alpha * (2 * eij * Q(k,j) - beta * P(i,k));
          Q(k,j) = Q(k,j) + alpha * (2 * eij * P(i,k) - beta * Q(k,j));
          end
      end
   end
end
```

The code tries to factorize R into P and Q, and approaching the nearest P and Q with an update rule. For example, let R = [3 4 0 1 1; 0 1 0 4 4; 5 4 3 1 0; 0 0 5 4 3; 5 3 0 2 1], K=2, alpha=0.01 and beta=0.015. In my real case, I will use a huge sparse matrix R (that's why I need vectorization), and K remain small (less than 10). The goal of the whole script is producing a prediction value for every 0 elements in R, based on the non zero elements. I got this code from [here](http://www.albertauyeung.com/mf.php), originally written in Python.

Comment: Can you describe what this code is doing, rather than asking us to decode your code?

Comment: (Incidentally, `endfor` and `endif` are not supported in Matlab.)

Comment: replace endfor and endif with simply end in Matlab

Comment: This code try to factorize R into P and Q, and approaching the nearest P and Q with an update rule

Comment: Maybe give an example input/output of the matrices R, P, Q?

Comment: You can use any R with some 0 elements in it (sparse). P and Q are randomly generated by the code.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like one of those cases that not all code can be vectorized. Still, you can make it a bit better than it is now.

```
[nr, nc] = size(R);
P = rand(nr, K);
Q = rand(K, nc);

for i = 1:nr
   for j = 1:nc
      if R(i,j) > 0
          eij = R(i,j) - P(i,:)*Q(:,j);
          P(i,:) = P(i,:) + alpha * (2 * eij * Q(:,j)' - beta * P(i,:));
          Q(:,j) = Q(:,j) + alpha * (2 * eij * P(i,:)' - beta * Q(:,j));
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: It is a bit better with vectorizing the innermost loop, but the problem is that the other two loops contribute the most number of loops, with a large size of R.

Answer (score 1):

Since the operations on `P` and `Q` are serial in nature (iterative updates) I do not think you can do much better. You can save the `if` in the loop:

```
[nr, nc] - size(R);
P = rand(nr, K);
Q = rand(K, nc);

[nzi nzj] = find( R > 0 );
for ii=1:numel(nzi)
    i = nzi(ii);
    j = nzj(ii);
    eij = R(i,j) - P(i,:)*Q(:,j);
    P(i,:) = P(i,:) + alpha * (2 * eij * Q(:,j)' - beta * P(i,:));
    Q(:,j) = Q(:,j) + alpha * (2 * eij * P(i,:)' - beta * Q(:,j));
end
```